# Nvidia Shield - Flickering Issue

Tags: hdmi

**Background**

I have an [Nvidia Shield](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YP9FBMM) connected to my TV and have used it for many months successfully. This morning when I turned it on, the screen was flickering: it will change to showing the home screen for about 1 second then either a black screen or the "snow" screen for about 4 seconds, repeating. I have not changed anything recently like cables, tv, or any hardware.

**What I have tried**

I did look online and most posts regarding this are 8 years old or so and suggest trying a new HDMI cable, unplugging and plugging in a bunch of times, or that the resolution is getting off. I did try a new cable and different tv but same issue.

When I boot it into safe mode the flickering goes away. If I try to change to any of the available refresh rates, it works fine in safe mode still but same behavior once I restart out of safe mode again.

I even tried a full factory reset and still have the same behavior.

**Question**

I am open to any suggestions for those who have had this issue before. My question is how do I fix the flickering behavior? More than likely it is a resolution issue, and maybe it is linked to some sort of recent firmware upgrade? I was not notified that there was one any time recently though.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue. The fact it works in Safe Mode which likely is using slightly different parts of the GPU silicon, suggest this is a hardware problem of some type. If you have eliminated the cable as being the problem, and eliminated the TV as the problem, you are only left with the common device that results in the behavior being recreated.